# Priority Web SDK vs REST API

Tags: rest, priority-web-sdk

When developing a website using Priority's new tools, in which cases would I be better served accessing Priority using the Web SDK than by using the REST API?

How about vice-versa?

Comment: I've added the tag. As a courtesy may you update (or write) the tag usage info?

Comment: thanks for the up-votes, but don't do it as they get corrected. https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on you needs.
REST API is mostly used to integrate with other applications while WEB SDK is used for building stand-alone applications.

You may of course use them both in the same app.

There are some technical differences:

1. REST API executes triggers at a **row** level while WEB SDK executes
   triggers at a **field** level.
2. REST API has no support for **procedures** and **choose/search
   lists** while the WEB SDK does.

I would recommend using the REST API for large data retrievals and the WEB SDK for smaller request.