# Priority-web-sdk : Specific number of rows

Tags: javascript, erp, priority-web-sdk

Can I retrieve a certain number of rows when calling `form.getRows`? If so what is the maximum?

Comment: 42! --- have you tried reading [their API Docs](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#getRows)?

Comment: Yes I have!! It doesn't mention an option to retrieve a certain amount of rows!! Hence the question.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Since you have expressed interest in this issue, I have a small favour to ask:
We're trying to build a community around Priority's Web-SDK. For that we need a [priority-web-sdk] tag, but we lack the SO reputation points necessary to create new tags. Since it appears that you are loaded with reputation points, would you be willing to add this tag to this question?

Comment: @Leor as the question relates specifically to the software in question I agree. Now we wait for the edit to be peer reviewed, but know that it may be rejected.

Comment: Much appreciated, @evolutionxbox. I couldn't ask for more.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Could you add the tag to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44636898/priority-web-sdk-vs-rest-api? Since it's my question I hope I might be able to accept it.

Comment: @Leor you should be able to edit your own questions.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I don't have enough reputation to create a new tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of rows is determined on the server-side. It's typically somewhere around 100.

To page through the rows, keep calling [getRows()](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#getRows), each time specifying the index of the first row to be retrieved.